# Storing input buttons into a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is there a way to store an input "button" into a MySQL database? What I would like to do is have the user enter information into a form that is sent into a database. When a record is retrieved, I want there to be a input button that appears next to the record which results in an actions when clicked. Is there a way to achieve this kind of result?

Instead of actually storing it, I've tried to just add the button to the `while` loop that reads the data from the database, but this just returned an error as expected.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Generally display elements such as input buttons aren't features of a database, which is intended to store the data entered into the form, rather than the UI itself. There are lots of ways to implement buttons for interacting with databases, but I think you might have better luck searching for terms outside of databases. You can use PHP to generate input tags conditionally depending on the results of a database query, for instance. e.g.

```
<?php if (found_data()) echo "<input type="button">Click Me</input>"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks you for actually giving me an answer, rather than a sarcastic comment and a down vote lol.